# Is @RequestMapping annotation a replacement of DWR?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, dwr

I'm new to the spring-boot framework and a little bit confused.
Previously we use DWR to convert JAVA method in server's war package to javascript function. In Spring boot is the annotation @RequestMapping  do the same? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

No, the [@RequestMapping annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) is not related to [Direct Web Remoting](http://directwebremoting.org/). The annotation is used in the controller layer of Spring web applications to map requests onto methods.

A typical example for a `RequestMapping` looks as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/users")
public ResponseEntity<List<Post>> getPosts() {
    [...]
}
```

This will map incoming `GET` requests to path `/users` to this method.